# Azure DataLake Gen1 python SDK for removing recursive Acl on directories

Tags: python, azure

I want to remove acl recursively in AzureData lake Gen1.

I can see the client APIs for Gen2.

But i can't find any client Apis for gen1.

Is it possible using python?

Below code is from [Microsoft Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-acl-python)
This is for DataLake Gen2

```
def remove_permission_recursively(is_default_scope):

    try:
        file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="my-container")

        directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("my-parent-directory")

        acl = 'user:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'

        if is_default_scope:
           acl = 'default:user:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'

        directory_client.remove_access_control_recursive(acl=acl)

    except Exception as e:
     print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have Python SDK to perform filesystem operations on Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1.

Here we need to install below modules:

```
pip install azure-mgmt-resource
pip install azure-mgmt-datalake-store
pip install azure-datalake-store
```

We have Microsoft documentation on this to explain about how we can handle file system operations on [Azure with DLS Gen1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-python).

Also, we have below methods which will help us to deal with ACL:

```
remove_acl(self, path)
remove_acl_entries(self, path, acl_spec, recursive=False, number_of_sub_process=None)
remove_default_acl(self, path)
```

To use them in a recursive way we have a parameter of Boolean type where we can specify whether we can remove ACL’s recursively or not.

For more details about these methods, refer to GitHub azure-datalake-store-python [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-python).

Below is the function for remove_acl_entries() in detail:

```
def remove_acl_entries(self, path, acl_spec, recursive=False, number_of_sub_process=None):
        """
        Remove existing, named, Access Control List (ACL) entries on a file or folder.
        If the entry does not exist already it is ignored.
        Default entries cannot be removed this way, please use remove_default_acl for that.
        Unnamed entries cannot be removed in this way, please use remove_acl for that.

        Note: this is by default not recursive, and applies only to the file or folder specified.

        Parameters
        ----------
        path: str
            Location to remove the ACL entries.
        acl_spec: str
            The ACL specification to remove from the ACL at the path in the format (note that the permission portion is missing)
            '[default:]user|group|other:[entity id or UPN],[default:]user|group|other:[entity id or UPN],...'
        recursive: bool
            Specifies whether to remove ACLs recursively or not
        """
        if recursive:
            multi_processor_change_acl(adl=self, path=path, method_name="rem_acl", acl_spec=acl_spec,
                                       number_of_sub_process=number_of_sub_process)
        else:
            self._acl_call('REMOVEACLENTRIES', path, acl_spec, invalidate_cache=True)
```

Comment: Hi @SaiKarri -MT can you help me how i can set acl_spec property.I mean some dummy example for group and group id

Comment: Hello, For acl_spec property: The ACL specification to remove from the ACL at the path in the format (note that the permission portion is missing) '[default:]user|group|other:[entity id or UPN],[default:]user|group|other:[entity id or UPN],...'

Comment: also you can import all the required modules and can use **remove_acl_entries(path, acl_spec, recursive=False, number_of_sub_process=None)** directly.. 

have a look on (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-datalake-store/azure.datalake.store.core.AzureDLFileSystem?view=azure-python#remove-acl-entries-path--acl-spec--recursive-false--number-of-sub-process-none-) for each parameter.